# Addition using EditText in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I need to add 4 different numbers that are going to be introduced in 4 different EditTexts by a user. I've made a code but I don't know how to take those 4 numbers and add them to have just one, can someone help me? Here's the code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Paquetes extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

Button solicitar;
Button volver;
EditText n1;
EditText n2;
EditText n3;
EditText n4;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_paquetes);
    solicitar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_solicitar);
    solicitar.setOnClickListener(this);
    volver = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2_v);
    volver.setOnClickListener(this);
    n1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n1);
    n2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n2);
    n3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n3);
    n4 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.n4);
}

@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        EditText uno = n1.getText();
        EditText dos = n2.getText();
        EditText tres = n3.getText();
        EditText cuatro = n4.getText();
        public int n{
            n = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
        }
        case R.id.button_solicitar:
            Toast.makeText(Paquetes.this, "¡Tu pedido ha sido solicitado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
            break;
        case R.id.button2_v:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
            break;
    }
}
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to parse each int from the edit text into Integers.

```
int uno = Integer.parseInt(n1.getText().toString());
int dos = Integer.parseInt(n2.getText().toString());
int tres = Integer.parseInt(n3.getText().toString());
int cuatro = Integer.parseInt(n4.getText().toString());
int sum = uno + dos + tres + cuatro;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// declare (globally) a collection to hold your EditText widgets
private ArrayList<EditText> values = new ArrayList<>(); 

// Add your EditText widgets to a collection (ArrayList chosen here) in the onCreate method after they are all initialized.
values.add(n1);
values.add(n2);
values.add(n3);
values.add(n4);

// complete your method in the onClick event to mimic the following
// preferably move this method outside onClick
public int addValues(ArrayList<EditText> edts) {
        int sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < edts.length; i++) {
            sum += Integer.parseInt(edts.get[i].getText().toString());
        }
        return sum;
    }

// call your method on a button click
addValues(values);
```

Your onClick method should look similar to this:

```
@Override
public void onClick (View v){
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.button_solicitar:
            addValues(values); // use the value returned by this method call however you want
            Toast.makeText(Paquetes.this, "¡Tu pedido ha sido solicitado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
            break;
        case R.id.button2_v:
            startActivity(new Intent(this, Casa.class));
            break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

int sum=(

Integer.getInteger(uno.getText().toString())+ Integer.getInteger(dos.getText().toString())+
Integer.getInteger(tres.getText().toString())+
Integer.getInteger(cuatro.getText().toString())

);